# Build a Visual Studio 2013 project in pure C

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

What is the best way to do this?  The templates seem to allow only for C++ (which is basically compatible with C, but not the same.)  What is the proper way to do this?  (A particular #define or whatever.)  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When creating the project, click on next, then uncheck the boxes below "empty project", then check the "empty project" box. This works for console and windows type programs.

Comment: Please note that Visual Studio doesn't follow the C standard.

Comment: Use a standard console C++ project empty project and add c files instead of cpp

Comment: @Lundin I thought VS2013 was basically C99.

Comment: @Jiminion It has never been good at following any C standard. If you are concerned about writing strictly conforming C programs, you should use a different compiler.

Comment: @Lundin  I don't disagree, but not an option.

Comment: what are the solutions ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is simple and easy

1. You create a new win32 console project
2. Remove the default .cpp file
3. Add new .c file as you wish
4. In Properties, under C/C++ --> All Options, find "Compile as", then select "Compile as C code"

[image: two muppets]

5. Simple sanity check. This code doesn't work with C++ since "new" is a reserved word for C++.

   int new = 10;

Comment: that's not enough. If you try `struct IDispatchVtbl foo;` and try `foo.` to see if intellisense can find members of foo, it won't work. also need `#ifdef __cplusplus #undef __cplusplus #endif`. surely there must be a workaround but I can't find one.

Comment: so how to solve this one?