# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 VERY basic help needed: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm doing an `Introduction to C Programming course` at the moment, only just started, and I am running into an issue I just can't get around. The course instructor is no help, and I know the issue is extremely basic, but every solution I find online assumes good working knowledge of the software. I don't have that, not yet anyway.

I'm simply trying to run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This is, I believe, supposed to display "Hello" on the screen when I run it. But when I press F5 to debug I get the following message:

`"Unable to start program. '[file path].Project1.exe' The system cannot find the file specified."`

So there needs to be a `.exe` file there, but how do I make one? I've searched through many other answers to similar issues across the web, but all of them make reference to things I simply don't understand yet, so I'm asking here for a layman's explanation of how to resolve this.

Thanks so much to anyone who can help.

Comment: Check the tag on your question. [tag:c#] is not [tag:c].

Comment: This might help: [Build a Visual Studio 2013 project in pure C](//stackoverflow.com/q/29946003)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build a Visual Studio 2013 project in pure C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946003/build-a-visual-studio-2013-project-in-pure-c)

Answer (score 0):

In your output window you are currently seeing that message in the `Debug`, right? You need to change that to `Build` or (I prefer) `Build Order` (which keeps the multi-threaded items in a sensible order for output). This will show you why your program didn't *build* - hence you have no "exe" to run.